# possible to assign a different value to a group than that which was matched using regex

Tags: python, regex

**The Question**

Is there a way to get the regex match method to assign a `'0'` in the case that a group matches to `''`?

**The Details**

I have a project that uses many different regular expressions evaluating a series of fields. Some fields are optionally blank, and in those cases the regex returns a match for the empty string (`''`).

For some of these field types, the field is meant to contain an integer and an empty string will later be interpreted by the program to mean zero.

In order to turn a blank into a `'0'`, I have done something like the following:

```
blank_to_zero = {'' : '0'}

my_value = my_regex.match('').group('FIELD_NAME')

number = int(blank_to_zero.get(my_value, my_value))
```

It would be nice- much more readable- to get rid of the `blank_to_zero.get(my_value, my_value)` bit and just have this:

```
number = int(my_value)
```

I'm sure there are other interesting ways to address this problem, but this question really is meant to be about returning some other literal with a regex group. If possible please stick to that issue.

So my question is: can this be done? Can you designate some literal to be returned by the expression match other than the string that has been matched to some group?

Comment: What do you mean when you say *using regex*? Because out of the box you can do [whatever MatchObject allows you to](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) (so you can't return anything else, but what `.group` returns), otherwise I think you need to implement some kind of parsing logic, like you did with the key lookup

Comment: @Adelin I just mean using the methods provided in the `re` implementation of the regex language, or perhaps some other implementation with more features.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a better alternative. Implement a function called `_int` to replace `int`.

```
def _int(object):
    if object == "":
        return 0
    else:
        return int(object)
```

Then you just need to use it like `number = _int(my_value)`

Further, you can override `int`.

```
def int(object):
    import builtins
    if object == "":
        return 0
    else:
        return builtins.int(object)
```

Comment: i get it but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @RickTeachey To directly answer your question, you cannot modify what `group` returns.